# How to convert a char array to a uint16_t by casting type pointer?

Tags: c++, casting, uint16

```
char bytes[2];
bytes[0] = 0; //0x00
bytes[1] = 24; //0x18
uint16_t* ptrU16 = (uint16_t*)bytes; // I expect it points to the memory block: 0x18
cout << *ptrU16 << endl;  // I expect 24, but it is 6144
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: It's all about [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Your expectation is wrong, not your code.

Comment: This violates [strict aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and perhaps also alignment

Comment: To the close voter: the question includes all the information, it's just hidden in the comments... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a little endian machine. `6144` is `0x1800`. When your machine represents the 16 bit value `0x0018` in memory, it puts the `0x18` byte first, and the `0x00` byte second, so when you interpret the two byte sequence `0x0018` as a `uint16_t`, it gives you `6144` (i.e. `0x1800`), and not `24` (i.e. `0x0018`).

If you change to:

```
bytes[0] = 24; 
bytes[1] = 0;
```

you'll likely see the result you expect.

If you really want to get the result you expect, then you'll either have to compute it manually, such as:

```
uint16_t n = (bytes[1] << 8) + bytes[0];
```

or, more generally:

```
char bytes[] = {0x18, 0x00};
uint16_t n = 0;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
    n += bytes[i] << 8 * i;
}
std::cout << n << std::endl;
```

or you can use a function like `ntohs()`, since network byte-order is big endian.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Very clear. So how can I correct my code to get what I want?

Comment: `(bytes[1] << 8)` this could be [problematic](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E5aesxzYY) in case of negative `char`; compiler switch `-Wconversion` strongly advised

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the `ntohs()` function. ("Network to Host byte order conversion"). You've plugged in your data in big endian mode, which is traditionally also network byte order. No matter what host you're on, the ntohs() function should return the value you're expecting. There's a mirror function for going from host to network order.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
...
cout << htons(*ptrU16) << endl;
```

should work and be portable across systems. (i.e. should work on Power, ARM, X86, Alpha, etc).